# Powershell csv find values with backslash only in particular column and rename them

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to filter csv file in column "Result" to get values with backslash and then rename them with appropriate name.

Here is example.csv

```
Accession,SrvDate,EntryDate,FinalReportDate,Patient First Name,Patient Last Name,DOB,Gender,Race, Ethnicity,Patient Address,Patient City, Patient State,Patient Zip,Patient Phone,Test Code,Test Name,Result,ClientID, Client Name,Phys  ID, Phys  Name
2132900941,NULL, 11-24-2020,11/29/2020,MICHELL,PENDERGRAS,09/30/1981,F,,U,35 RUSEVELT ST,PRUDENCE, RB,2909, (401)516-5642,Z620, Sars-COVID19, Positive,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2232900942,NULL, 11-25-2020,11/29/2020,MICHEL,PENDERGRA, 9/30/1982,M,,U,315 RUSEVELT ST,PRUDENCE, RB,2909, (401)516-5643,Z620, Sars-COVID19, Negative,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2332900943,NULL, 11-26-2020,11/29/2020,MICHE,PENDERGR,  9/30/1983,F,,U,325 RUSEVELT ST,PRUDENCE, RB,2909, (401)516-5644,Z620, Sars-COVID19, \989,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2432900944,NULL, 11-27-2020,11/29/2020,MICH,PENDERG,  9/30/1984,M,,U,335 RUSEVELT ST,PRUDENCE, RB,2909, (401)516-5645,Z620, Sars-COVID19, \990,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2532900945,NULL, 11-28-2020,11/29/2020,ALLISO,JEZA,10/13/1977,F,,U,15 KAUTEEKEE AVE, SOUTH PRUDENCE,RB,2911, (908)930-9213,Z620, Sars-COVID19, \61,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2632900946,NULL, 11-29-2020,11/29/2020,ALLIS,JEZ, 10/13/1978,M,,U,151 KAUTEEKEE AVE,SOUTH PRUDENCE,RB,2911, (908)930-9214,Z620, Sars-COVID19, \990,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2732900947,NULL, 11-30-2020,11/29/2020,ALLI,JE,  10/13/1979,F,,U,152 KAUTEEKEE AVE,SOUTH PRUDENCE,RB,2911, (908)930-9215,Z620, Sars-COVID19, @,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
2832900948,NULL, 12-1-2020,11/29/2020,ALL,J,  10/13/1980,M,,U,153 KAUTEEKEE AVE,SOUTH PRUDENCE,RB,2911, (908)930-9216,Z620, Sars-COVID19, Positive,99984,"ASHRAF FARID, M.D.",50845,ATPAV RIGTED
```

\990 should be named as "Presumptive Positive"

\989 should be named as "Invalid"

\61  should be named as "QNS"

Here is a script that I tried to use to simply filter backslash values, but then I've stuck:

```
$inval = [regex]::escape('\989')
$prespos = [regex]::escape('\990')
$in = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\example.csv).Fullname | ? "Result" -in $inval, $prespos
```

or like this:

```
$in = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\example.csv).Fullname | ? "Result" -in "\990", "\989"
```

But variable $in have no output.

Could you please help me solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you wanting to replace `\989` with `Invalid` or if the `result` column contains `\989`, then set the `result` column value to be `Invalid`? Your condition is failing because you are testing property `Test Result` instead of `Result`. Using `-in` will only work if the strings match exactly.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thank you, I fixed that in my question. I've tried with correct property, but put wrong in example. I have multiple additional filters in my full script, but completely stuck with these backslashes. When script will find result with \989 or \990 it should also check for duplicates, do additional calculations and then export result in file or send by email. But I'm covered with all of that. I face the issue when I was forced to include \989 and \990 beside "Positive". I will try to use your suggestion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like the following provided the `Result` field contains exact matches for the data you want to replace.

```
# read Csv as object in $data
$data = Import-Csv example.csv
# hash of replacement values
$hash = @{'\990' = 'Presumptive Positive'; '\989' = 'Invalid'; '\61' = 'QNS'}
# only select rows that need to be replaced
foreach ($row in $data | Where Result -in $hash.keys) {
    # update current row result with replacement value
    $row.Result = $hash[$row.Result]
}
# output object as CSV
$data | Export-Csv output.csv -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I successfully inserted your script and tested it. Result is wonderful!